# Spring-Hibernate Transactional Read-only propagation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I read about Transaction propagation and about read-only.
But there's something which is not clear to me.

Let's say i have this code:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void first() {
    second();
}

@Transactional
public void second() {
    //do Something
}
```

What will happen?
Will the first method be suspended, since it cannot be flushed/committed, and the second method needs that? 
Or maybe the 'read-only' is also propagated to inner call? (Since i am in 'required' propagation mode)?

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature called `progagation` which you define on the `@Transactional` annotation.

There are two options that could fit into the inner transactions scenario

**`NESTED`**:

> Execute within a nested transaction if a current transaction exists,
>   behave like PROPAGATION_REQUIRED else. There is no analogous feature
>   in EJB. Note: Actual creation of a nested transaction will only work
>   on specific transaction managers. Out of the box, this only applies to
>   the JDBC DataSourceTransactionManager when working on a JDBC 3.0
>   driver. Some JTA providers might support nested transactions as well.

**REQUIRES_NEW**

> PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW starts a new, independent "inner" transaction
>   for the given scope. This transaction will be committed or rolled back
>   completely independent from the outer transaction, having its own
>   isolation scope, its own set of locks, etc. The outer transaction will
>   get suspended at the beginning of the inner one, and resumed once the
>   inner one has completed.

As the outer transaction is marked as `readOnly` then the `NESTED` option does not make sense as the commit of the inner transaction is dependent on the outer transaction.. and the outer does not allow any changes to take place..

So in my opinion only the

```
@Transaction(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void second(..)
```

makes sense in this scenario.

Just to underline.. this should work in theory.. there are many factors to consider.. database features, library version etc.. you would have to do some further testing, but hopefully this gives you an idea.

**Update**

To bypass this.. try to make another .. higher level service which would not be transactional.. then you could inject the lower level service and perform the calls sequentially without nested transactions problem:

```
    @Service
    public class FacadeService{

       @Autowired 
       private TransactionalService service;

       public void perform(..){

            service.first(); 
            service.second();
            ...
       }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know that my code is not optimal. I am just not sure what's going on. I know that the propagation is 'required'.  I read somewhere: "Conversely, if you call a method from within a readOnly transaction that requires read/write, again, the first one will be suspended, since it cannot be flushed/committed, and the second method needs that". But on the other hand why the 'read-only' is not propagating to the inner one?

Comment: why should it propagate.. the inner transaction is not marked as readOnly.. it would be created with its own features

Comment: I was not sure. I thought that maybe the inner transaction is 'inheriting' the outer one (since the propagation is required and it will try to use an existing transaction)

Comment: like i said you have to test on your environment as this will eventaully tell the truth. I just gave you some idea. Hopefully they will be of value to you.